# Is it already possible to write "transform" css property without prefix?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

HTML5 animation is widely used now days but developers are forced to use wrappers for the hardware animation functions to write cross browser applications. Simple function like "transform" is stil should be written like:

```
.foo {
  -webkit-transform: (10%, 20%); 
       -o-transform: (10%, 20%); 
     -moz-transform: (10%, 20%);
      -ms-transform: (10%, 20%); 
}
```

but some browsers might produce and the do produce the warnings on the unknown and other platform specific CSS properties. It could be fixed by sending the browser specific CSS.

BUT. How would you recommend to write the

```
.foo {transform: (10%, 20%)}
```

once for all supported browsers. Is it already possible now days to write it with only one standard non prefixed property?

Answer (score 3):

You have been searching for [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/).

> -prefix-free lets you use only unprefixed CSS properties everywhere. It works behind the scenes, adding the current browser’s prefix to any
>   CSS code, only when it’s needed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the browser. Generally `box-shadow` and `border-radius` are prefix safe. Below picture is your answer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no. I think best practice (in terms of support) is to write every vendor prefix as well as the W3C drafted property as shown:

```
    .foo {
  -webkit-transform: translate(10%, 20%); 
  -o-transform: translate(10%, 20%);
  -moz-transform: translate(10%, 20%);
  -ms-transform: translate(10%, 20%); 
  transform: translate(10%, 20%);

/*The working draft requires values as transform-functions like transform(), not just
value pairs as shown in the question*/

}
```

The prefixed properties are essentially development features and **not necessarily stable**, and you shouldn't worry too much about flags there, as the browser will usually disable properties it can't read. Just check to see if your pages are breaking on different browsers for now. The final spec will hopefully come in the near future, and then you'll be able to take out the prefixed declarations. Meanwhile, you can keep track of the working draft [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/).